# In Eclipse Luna how to skip all breakpoints except one?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

I have multiple breakpoints in a Java project. I want to skip them all (except one) for the current session only and stop at that one particular breakpoint while debugging. How can that be achieved in the quickest way?

Comment: Go to the [breakpoints view](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-breakpoints_view.htm) and control which breakpoints you want to skip.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Can I do it without individually clicking on each breakpoint in breakpoint view?

Comment: Skip all, then go to that window and select only desired breakpoint.

Comment: @user13107 ctrl-a to select all breakpoints, then rightclick -> disable, then enable the one you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by GUIDO, solution is to `ctrl-a to select all breakpoints, then rightclick -> disable, then enable the one you want`